# Elasticsearch - Synonym analyzer seems to take no effect in analyzing

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am trying to update my settings for one of the indexes (specifically, I want to update my custom analyzer to use my custom synonym filter). I wrote the following to update the setting, and it compiles without the error, but seems like the synonym filter isn't working as expected (the synonyms I specified seem like has no effect). I want Harry Potter and HP to be the same thing, and Terminator and TM to be the same thing as well (As a side note, I am closing and then updating index and then open it back again).

```
client.close('movies')
client.put_settings(index='movies', body={
        "settings": {
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "custom_analyzer": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "filter": "my_synonyms"
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "custom_synonyms": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms": ["Harry Potter,HP => HP", "Terminator, TM => TM"]

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    })
    client.open('movies')
```

And here is my original index setting with mapping:

```
client.create(
    index = "movies",
    body= {
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "custom_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                } 
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "body": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                    "search_quote_analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    ignore=400 
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how are you verifying it's not working?

Comment: I have a search query (searching for "HP") that queries the movies index and I'm trying to rank the documents so that the document containing "Harry Potter" 5 times is the top element in the list. Right now, it seems like the document with "HP" 3 times tops the list.

Comment: You should also show your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take effect you would need to re-index whole data.
Reindexing will map such synonyms.
Just open and close would not help.